# combining inbound channel adapters and stream emitter

Tags: kotlin, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, reactive

I'm playing with spring cloud stream reactive and I'm facing a problem.

Consider the following code:

```
@InboundChannelAdapter("list", poller = [(Poller(fixedDelay = "\${thetis.listInterval:60000}"))])
fun timerMessageSource(): Flux<Center> = config.centers.toFlux()
```

My goal here is to generate a flux that shall be consumed by something of the form:

```
 @StreamListener("list") @Output("download")
 fun processList(center: Center): Flux<Product> = ...
```

But this does not seems to works. The channel adapter correctly generates fluxes, but it says the following:

```
 org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'FluxIterable': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```

I thought that I shall add a `StreamEmitter` annotation along the inbound channel adapter, but that does not seems to work.

What is the correct way of implementing such a flow?

Thank you and regards,

Fernando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is pretty clear: you produce a `Flux` object as a `payload` of the message to send to the `list` channel to be emitted to the target destination on the messaging middleware. And that it fully correct that `Flux` as is is not compatible with the JSON to be serialized.

On the other hand I'm not sure what is Kotlin and compile your code to Java, but we have out-of-the-box something like this (for Java):

```
@StreamEmitter
@Output("list")
public Flux<Center> timerMessageSource() {
     return config.centers.toFlux();
}
```

And each emitted item in the flux will be serialized and sent as a record or message to the Binder. If your `Center` is JSON compatible, of course. For this purpose you need a `spring-cloud-stream-reactive` dependency.

Right, the `@InboundChannelAdapter` doesn't help here or even disturbs.

If you worry about some periodic emitting, if should consider scheduling support in the [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers).

Comment: thank you, it works now. I'm still studying this stuff and there are many things I don't fully understand :)